# MS SQL Server 2008 R2 downloads for practice

Tags: sql, tsql, ssms

I plan to download MS SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 - Express Edition.  I know I need one of the two applications to download with it: 1) SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Tools and 2) SQL Server 2008 R2 - Management Studio Express.  Which one (1 or 2) is best for me to download??  This is in terms of me just honing and practicing my skills on T-SQL and other basic to intermediate tasks on SQL Server 2008.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You should install `SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe`  or `SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe` depending on the architecture which is full version express edition. If you want Management studio, you can download the management studio separately and install it later.

Check the following link for more details:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30438